# Accessing a Java data member (a property) only within the class and by child class, but not in package

Tags: java, oop

I have a scenario of OOPs in Java, which I am curious about,
I want to have a variable/data member/property in my class such that:

1. It should only be accessed in the class where it has been defined
2. It should only be accessed by an child class which has extended this class
3. And should NOT BE accessed easily by a class inside the same package or any other package

It may sound like an unrealistic scenario, but I am curious that how can we achieve this.

Below is the sample code I am trying with:

```
class Point {
    // protected int x, y;
    int x, y;

  public Point()
    {
    }
    public Point(int _x, int _y)
    {
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Point p = new Point();
        System.out.println("x = " + p.x + ", y = " + p.y);
    }
}
```

1. Output when x and y are protected : 0 and 0
2. Output when x and y are private : Compilation Error
3. Output when using default access modifier on x and y : 0 and 0

If any one has any solution or any approach for tackling this scenario is very much appreciated.
And also I know Java currently has no such access modifier, but still I want to understand why and why not.

Comment: When you say `Point p = new Point();`, you are creating an instance of a class, not a child. A child class is when you extend a parent class, such as `public class point2 extends point { ... }`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Hi Jordan, apologize for late response was stuck in a situation where I cant put my time on this,
A child class is when you extend a parent class, such as public class point2 extends point { ... } -- YES

Comment: It looks to me that private is the correct access modifier. Since Test is outside of the the Point class, it will satisfy 1 and 3.  Children inherit all variables and methods, regardless of access modifiers, satisfying 2.

Comment: Actually, I want to have such an access modifier , that my x and y variable is private but should be visible to only child classes, no other class in package or outside the same package should be able to see the x and y data member.
Currently, protected access modifier opens up the data member to other classes of the package,
One solution is to use a different package itself  for the above two classes.
Let me know if i need to edit my question for clarity.